# Mask text after character in QListWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, mask, qlistwidget

I have a QListWidget and I would like to hide all text after the first : while the full string is still there for me to use, for all the items.

Example:

```
List item | username:password
```

What I want:

```
List Item (Password is still there but hidden) | username
```

This is just to make the UI cleaner, are there any built in PyQT functions which could help me achieve this or would I have to come up with some other solution using Python? Reproducable example is just a QListWidget with items that have : in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a delegate:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Delegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def displayText(self, value, locale):
        text = super().displayText(value, locale)
        separator = ":"
        values = text.split(separator)
        if len(values) == 2:
            username, password = values
            mask_character = chr(
                QtWidgets.QApplication.style().styleHint(
                    QtWidgets.QStyle.SH_LineEdit_PasswordCharacter
                )
            )
            return separator.join([username, mask_character * len(password)])
        return text


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
    delegate = Delegate(w)
    w.setItemDelegate(delegate)
    w.show()

    for i in range(10):
        text = f"username{i}:password{i}"
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(text)
        item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable)
        w.addItem(item)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is really cool actually, but what I specifically want it to do is make the characters after the separator invisible as opposed to password characters.

Edit: Figured it out, just changed mask_character to "" 

Thanks a lot!